# Toggling JMS Listener on/off causes listener to hang

Tags: spring, jms, listener, freeze

We have a Spring project (3.0.5) that is listening to a JMS queue (WebSphere 7). We need the ability to toggle the queue listener on/off. We are currently programmatically calling DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start() and stop() via our own RESTful endpoint to toggle the listener on/off.

We have observed that after toggling the listener on two or three times (on/off/on or on/off/on/off/on) the listener goes into a hung state and we cannot toggle it off.

To debug what is going on we have our log level set to Trace. When the listener is turned on successfully we see the following message in our log:

XXXX-XX-XX [myListenerContainer-1] TRACE c.g.c.r.c.m.MessageListenerContainer - doReceiveAndExecute - Consumer [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@45486b51] of session [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession@1872c950] did not receive a message

However, the last time we turn on the listener before it hangs, we fail to see this message in the log.

Extra details:

- Getting to the hung state is reproducible with or without messages entering the queue.
- The last time we turn on the listener before it hangs, we can "correct" the hung state by putting a message on the queue. once a message is received we see the healthy trace messages in the log and we are able to toggle the listener off.